# If $A>0$ , $B>0$ , $A-B>0$ then $\rho (A) - \rho (B) > 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let $A,B\in M_n$, suppose

- $A>0$ (i.e, all $a_{ij}>0$)
- $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$
- $B>0$
- $A-B>0$

Why does $\rho (A) - \rho (B) > 0$?

Comment: We could also prove this using some results from Horn and Johnson that are weaker than the PF theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED: 
Let $A(t) = B + t (A-B)$ interpolate linearly between $B$ at $t=0$ and $A$ at $t=1$.  Thus $A(t)$ is a positive matrix and so is its derivative $A'(t)$.
By Perron-Frobenius, $\rho(A(t)) = \lambda(t)$ is a simple eigenvalue, with left and right eigenvectors $v^T(t)$, $u(t)$ having positive entries; we can normalize them so that 
$v(t)^T u(t) = 1$.  Moreover, $\lambda(t)$, $v^T(t)$, $u(t)$ are differentiable (in fact real-analytic) as functions of $t$.  Differentiating $v(t)^T u(t) = 1$ 
we get $v(t)^T u'(t) + v'(t)^T u(t)= 0$.
Now differentiating the equation $\lambda(t) = v(t)^T A(t) u(t)$ we get
$$ \eqalign{\lambda'(t) &= v'(t)^T A(t) u(t) + v(t)^T A'(t) u(t) + v(t)^T A(t) u'(t)\cr
&= \lambda(v'(t)^T u(t) + v(t)^T u'(t)) + v(t)^T A'(t) u(t)\cr &= v(t)^T A'(t) u(t) > 0}$$

Comment: I have a question: If the derivative of the $\lambda (t)$ is positive wouldn't this imply that $\lambda (1) > \lambda ( 0)$, i.e. $\rho(B) > \rho(A)$

Comment: Oops, interchanged $A$ and $B$.  I'll edit.

Comment: Ack.  Need left and right eigenvectors... edited.

Comment: Why is it that we're able to normalize $v(t)^Tu(t)=1$ here?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato Because a nonzero multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Hints : Let $x$ be the Perron vector of $A$ , so that $Ax>Bx$ and ......

Comment: Please more guide,

Comment: Although the Question may require a bit of parsing to make sense of it, I think this "hint" does not go into as much detail as it should to clarity the situation.

Comment: @Robert Israel - Thanks. What is intended purpose 'Nokia'?